# Select distinct column and then count 2 columns that relate to that column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have an error log that I need to analyze.

In that error log there is are fields called

- EVENT_ATTRIBUTE that displays the name of the device that collected that information.
- EVENT_SEVERITY that displays a number from 1 to 5. In this column I need to find the amount 4's and 5's.

The problem is I need to get the distinct EVENT_ATTRIBUTES and then count all the 4's and 5's related to that specific EVENT_ATTRIBUTE and output the count.

Basically the sensors(event_attribute) detect different errors. I need to analyze how many 4's and 5's each of the sensors picks up so that I can analyze them.

I am having problems taking the distinct sensors and linking them to the specific sensor. I have tried this so far but it only returns me same number for 4 and 5 so I don't think I am doing it correctly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, locate('(', EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, 1)-1) AS 
SensorName, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN 'EVENT_SEVERITY' <>5 THEN 1 END) AS ERROR5,
COUNT(CASE WHEN 'EVENT_SEVERITY' <>4 THEN 1 END) AS ERROR4
FROM nodeapp.disc_event
WHERE EVENT_SEVERITY IN (5,4)
Group BY SensorName;
```

Here is the table that I am looking at.
[Event Error Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk4dq.png)

Im truncating the event attribute because the IP address doesn't matter. Basically I want to make the unique event_attribute act as a primary key and count the amount of 4's and 5's connected to that primary key.

With the code above I get this output: [Event Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPNti.png)

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: don't you want `WHEN 'EVENT_SEVERITY' = 5 THEN 1` instead of `<> 5` ?

Comment: If you want the count of "4's" and "5's", why is your query count the number of "not 4's" and "not 5's"? Oh, I see, you're filtering down to 4 & 5 in where...still weird (especially when "not 5" is aliased as "ERROR5").

Comment: It's generally better to include text of sample data rather than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.

`DISTINCT` is unnecessary when you're grouping.

You want `SUM()`. `COUNT()` simply counts everything that's not null.  You can exploit the hack that a boolean expression evaluates to either 1 or 0.

```
 SELECT LEFT(EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, LOCATE('(', EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, 1)-1) AS SensorName, 
        SUM(EVENT_SEVERITY = 5) ERROR_5,
        SUM(EVENT_SEVERITY = 4) ERROR_4,
        COUNT(*) ALL_ERRORS
   FROM nodeapp.disc_event
  GROUP BY LEFT(EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, LOCATE('(', EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, 1)-1);
```

Even if `EVENT_SEVERITY` values are stored as strings in your DBMS, expressions like `EVENT_SEVERITY = 4` implicitly coerce them to integers.

It's generally good practice to include batch totals like `COUNT(*)` especially when you're debugging; they form a good sanity check that you're handling your data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The query is interpreting `'EVENT_SEVERITY'` as string, try using ` or double quotes to delimit the field instead. ...and while it is "standard", I tend to shy away from double-quotes because they look like they should be for strings (and in some configurations of MySQL are).

**Edit (for clarity):** I mean it is literally interpreting `'EVENT_SEVERITY'` as the string "EVENT_SEVERITY", not the underlying value of the field as a string.